# How WHERE works with column name only?

Tags: mysql

I have table with varchar column. Some rows are empty, some have content.
While preparing SELECT statement, I accidentaly run query like that:

```
SELECT column_x FROM table_x WHERE column_x;
```

It gave me all rows where column_x content begins with numbers. How WHERE condition works in this case and why it selects that values but not values which begins with letters or special signs?

Comment: `column_x` can be, or interpreted as a boolean.

Comment: What Colin said above. `column_x` values are converted to integers and then 0 is interpreted as FALSE and any other number as TRUE.

Comment: If you run `SELECT column_x, CAST(column_x AS UNSIGNED) FROM table_x ;`, you can see the result of the cast.

Comment: Exactly, value "11a" is converted to "11", and "a11" to "0", so it must be conversion to integer. Now I understand what's going on, thanks!